# WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies in Wildfly 26 with EJB SecurityDomain annotation

Tags: wildfly, elytron, wildfly-26, securitydomain

We've got an application with several web services annotated with @SecurityDomain("our-ws") (I've also tried setting this in jboss-web.xml).   For example:

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(OurTransactionInterceptor.class)
@WebService(targetNamespace = "...", portName = "AddStuff", serviceName = "AddStuffService")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
@WebContext(authMethod = "BASIC", contextRoot = "/service", urlPattern = "/AddStuffService")
@SecurityDomain("our-ws")
public class AddStuffService  { ... }
```

We are upgrading to Wildfly 26, and attempting to use elytron following the example from
[WildFly Elytron Security](https://docs.wildfly.org/26.1/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#set-up-and-configure-authentication-for-applications), section 4.1.3.  However, on startup, I'm getting an error like:

```
13 Jan 2023 11:26:01,763 ERROR [management-operation  Controller Boot Thread] WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "service.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.security.security-domain.our-ws"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"service.war\".component.AddStuffService.CREATE is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.our-ws]"]
}
```

In standalone.xml, under `<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron:15.1"...>`  We've got a datasource, which I'll call 'ourDS' (not shown) used by a jdbc-realm, jdbc:

```
            <jdbc-realm name="jdbc">
                <principal-query sql="SELECT password FROM CFG_WS_USERS_T WHERE username=?" data-source="evercoreDS">
                    <clear-password-mapper password-index="1"/>
                </principal-query>
                <principal-query sql="SELECT roles from CFG_WS_ROLES_T r join CFG_WS_USERS_T u on u.WS_USERS_PK=r.WS_USERS_FK where u.username=?" data-source="ourDS">
                    <attribute-mapping>
                        <attribute to="roles" index="1"/>
                    </attribute-mapping>
                </principal-query>
            </jdbc-realm>
```

And a security-domain for those web services:

```
        <security-domain name="our-ws" default-realm="jdbc" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
            <realm name="jdbc" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
        </security-domain>
```

So I don't get why jboss.security.security-domain.our-ws is not installed (unless, maybe, it is looking for it in the legacy security configuration.).

How, do I get the SecurityDomain annotation (or the security-domain tag in jboss-web.xml) to refer to the elytron configuration, or why would my security-domain under elytron not be installed?

**EDIT**:  In response to @ehsavoie's comment, I'll note that, per section 4.1.3 of the doc, we also have an http-authentication-factory and application-security-domain:

```
        <http-authentication-factory name="our-ws-http-auth" security-domain="our-ws" http-server-mechanism-factory="global">
            <mechanism-configuration>
                <mechanism mechanism-name="BASIC">
                    <mechanism-realm realm-name="our-ws"/>
                </mechanism>
            </mechanism-configuration>
        </http-authentication-factory>

    <application-security-domains>
        <application-security-domain name="defaultASD" security-domain="ApplicationDomain"/>
        <application-security-domain name="our-ws-appsecurity-domain" http-authentication-factory="our-ws-http-auth"/>
    </application-security-domains>
```

(I'm a bit confused by the `mechanism-realm realm-name="our-ws"`, since `our-ws` is not a security-realm, but a security-domain, but it follows the documentation - again section 4.1.3-- and I also tried using the `jdbc` security-realm there, with the the same error.)

Comment: I'm wondering if you are needing this:You need to make your application security domain 

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:5.0">
...
    <application-security-domains>
        <application-security-domain name="our-ws" security-domain="our-ws"/>
    </application-security-domains>
...
</subsystem>

Comment: @ehsavoie: I already have an application-security-domain defined, per the doc.  I've updated my question to include that.

Comment: yes but in elytron subsystem. I was referencing the ejb3 subsystem

Comment: @ehsavoie:   Yes that _seems_ to have made a difference.  I'm think I've gotten past the original error, and am now getting a _different_ set of warnings/errors:  `UT015020: Path /MyService is secured for some HTTP methods, however it is not secured for [TRACE, HEAD, DELETE, GET, CONNECT, OPTIONS, PUT] and `The required mechanism 'SSO' is not available in mechanisms [BASIC] from the HttpAuthenticationFactory`.  Thanks.